# How to filter counts in WooCommerce product categories widget

Tags: woocommerce

I want to filter the counts that appear in WooCommerce's "Product Categories" widget.  I'm hiding certain products based on user role, for example category "Widgets" has 5 products total, but a given user may only see 1 of them.  So I want the category to be shown like "Widgets (1)" instead of "Widgets (5)".

My first thought on how to do this was to filter `get_terms`.  For some reason however, no matter what I do the count will never change.  I can change other things like the name, but not the count.

Example -- let's say I have 2 categories: Alcohol (4) and Widgets (5).  I add the following code:

```
add_filter( 'get_terms', 'test_20200822' ), 10, 2 );
function test_20200822( $terms, $taxonomy ) {
    if ( in_array( 'product_cat', $taxonomy ) ) {
        foreach ( $terms as $i => $term ) {
            if ( is_a( $term, 'WP_Term' ) ) {
                // prepend an "X" to the name... this works correctly:
                $terms[$i]->name = 'X'.$terms[$i]->name;
                // change the count to 1... this doesn't work:
                $terms[$i]->count = 1;
            }
        }
    }
    return $terms;
}
```

The result is:

[image]

As you can see, the names are changed, but the counts are not.  What am I missing here?

Note 1: Whatever this is, its specific to WooCommerce.  If I use the same code on regular WordPress categories it works fine and changes the counts as expected.

Note 2: I'm asking this here on SO because the WordPress StackExchange says WooCommerce is off-topic there.

Answer (score 0):

Well, after sleeping on it I figured it out.  Changing my hook's priority to something greater than 10 makes it work. :facepalm:

The reason for this is because WooCommerce itself hooks into `get_terms` at priority 10 and overrides the term counts.  Found this in the file `woocommerce/includes/wc-term-functions.php`:

```
/**
 * Overrides the original term count for product categories and tags with the product count.
 * that takes catalog visibility into account.
 *
 * @param array        $terms      List of terms.
 * @param string|array $taxonomies Single taxonomy or list of taxonomies.
 * @return array
 */
function wc_change_term_counts( $terms, $taxonomies ) {
    if ( is_admin() || is_ajax() ) {
        return $terms;
    }

    if ( ! isset( $taxonomies[0] ) || ! in_array( $taxonomies[0], apply_filters( 'woocommerce_change_term_counts', array( 'product_cat', 'product_tag' ) ), true ) ) {
        return $terms;
    }

    $o_term_counts = get_transient( 'wc_term_counts' );
    $term_counts   = $o_term_counts;

    foreach ( $terms as &$term ) {
        if ( is_object( $term ) ) {
            $term_counts[ $term->term_id ] = isset( $term_counts[ $term->term_id ] ) ? $term_counts[ $term->term_id ] : get_term_meta( $term->term_id, 'product_count_' . $taxonomies[0], true );

            if ( '' !== $term_counts[ $term->term_id ] ) {
                $term->count = absint( $term_counts[ $term->term_id ] );
            }
        }
    }

    // Update transient.
    if ( $term_counts !== $o_term_counts ) {
        set_transient( 'wc_term_counts', $term_counts, DAY_IN_SECONDS * 30 );
    }

    return $terms;
}
add_filter( 'get_terms', 'wc_change_term_counts', 10, 2 );
```

Mentioning this here in case anyone else ends up in the same situation.